# Smarter sharePoint Forms. Redirect to another list based on entry on the first list?

Tags: list, redirect, sharepoint

On Moss 2007.

Without completely ripping apart the native SharePoint generated list newform.  Is there any way to redirect users to another list's newform based on what they enter in the current list newform?

Maybe, can the source redirect point to a form that interpreting fields passed in a query string and then decide where to take the user?

By chance is this any more possible in SP 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to create a new 'NewForm' that inherits from the standard NewForm and add the redirect logic to the page after the form has been submitted.  [This thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/121b1053-37fc-4ba2-b235-b577d50625a5#67dbfdb7-3456-458b-beaf-cb6b830aa704) looks like it can get you started on how to override the page.

Another approach may be a custom web part that checks the status of the list and performs the redirect.  Maybe you can do something with Javascript and the content editor web part.

Event receivers will not work, as they happen asynchronously and have no sharepoint context associated with them, in other words, you can't perform a redirect from them.